# How to find the sum of values that are inside a nested array using mongodb aggregation?

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, nested, sum

I am using node.js and writing a script using the Express framework. I am using cloud Mongodb and don't have access to a mongo shell, so I can't check output easily. I have to put the result in an array, using the `toArrray` function, so that I can see what's being put out. Console.log helps but sometimes it shows just `[]` when it is an object, although I can see the properties within the object if I check Postman.

I have a document that I have been sending down an aggregation pipeline in mongodb and at this point, where I am stuck, the output that appears in `res.send` is this:

```
[ { japanese_array: [ {"k": "japanese3a", "v": { "question": "japanese3a", "value": 100}}, 
                      {"k": "japanese3b", "v": { "question": "japanese3b", "value": 100}}, 
                      {"k": "japanese3c", "v": { "question": "japanese3c", "value": 100}} ] } ]
```

I want to add the fields called "value", so the desired output is just a number (300).

It's taken a long time to arrive at this point as there was a lot of trouble following examples of solutions in Stackoverflow as they seem to use a lot of quotes (eg. "$project"), and if I copy the examples in my script, with the quotes included, the script does not work. I have to remove the quotes around $project, etc to get the thing working. I don't understand why putting quotes around certain words work for other people and it doesn't for me. I am using mongodb version 4.2.

I have checked other similar questions in stackoverflow for days, but none of the solutions work for me.

The one that was closest to answering it for me is from here: [How to sum every fields in a sub document of MongoDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17661461/how-to-sum-every-fields-in-a-sub-document-of-mongodb)

But it still does not work. I have tried summing `"$japanese_array.v.value"` in a `$group` expression but it's not working, and I am stuck at the point that's shown here.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem.

I did this additional stage to the pipeline:

```
{$project: {_id:0, "result":{$sum: "$japanese_array.v.value"}}}
```

I asked a similar question 2 days ago and the answer I got then [How do you sum the values within an object which is a nested subdocument in mongodb using node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66194193/how-do-you-sum-the-values-within-an-object-which-is-a-nested-subdocument-in-mong) helped me find a solution here.